# Feature Detection With Modernizr Not Working?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I'm trying to use Modernizr to detect if the browser supports certain audio codecs, and it doesn't seem to be doing what I expected.

I ran the following

```
if(Modernizr.audio.mp4){

     //Do Something

}
```

But when I tested on Safari (which supports MP4), any logic inside the brackets was not hit. Perhaps I have my logic wrong, or I'm not understanding what Modernizr actually does?

All I want to do is test if the browser supports MP4 audio or not. Modernizr seemed to be the consensus to do this.

Any insights?

Thanks!

Comment: From the documentation: "Modernizr tests ogg, mp3, wav and m4a." Maybe you meant to type `m4a` instead of `mp4`?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `Modernizr.audio.m4a`.

On my browser, `Modernizr.audio.m4a` is "maybe" (true), while `Modernizr.audio.mp4` is "undefined" (false).

Refer to the [documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/#audio) for more details.

Comment: Great, thanks Wander. I wasn't getting the "Maybe" response as well, so thanks for clarifying that. And yes, I had entered incorrectly as mp4 instead of m4a.